# smallest divisor of an integer without computing the square root explcitly

Tags: c, algorithm, performance

This code gives the smallest divisor of an integer. But the problem is I have to calculate the square root. Is there a way so that I don't have to calculate the square root explicitly?

```
int d,r,n;
scanf("%d",&n);
if(n%2==0)
{
    printf("2 is ans"); 
}
else
{
    r=sqrt(n);
    d=3;
    while((n%d!=0)&&d<r)
    {
        d=d+2; 
    }
    if(n%d==0)
        printf("ans is %d",d);
    else
        printf("ans is 1");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `code-efficiency` was one of the tags, tweak the answers provided a bit:

```
while ((n%d) && (d<n/d)) d+=2;
```

The compiler is more likely to reuse the result of the division operator this way.

Looking at the compiler output for `gcc -O3` on the version of the loop I propose, there is only one division operation per iteration, and the result is used for both comparisons:

```
L18:
        cmpl    %esi, %ecx
        jle     L13
        movl    %ebx, %eax
        addl    $2, %esi
        cltd
        idivl   %esi
        testl   %edx, %edx
        movl    %eax, %ecx
        jne     L18
        .p2align 4,,15
L13:
```

While, the `while ((n%d) && d*d < n) d+=2;` version gives:

```
L8:
        movl    %ecx, %eax
        imull   %ecx, %eax
        cmpl    %ebx, %eax
        jge     L3
        movl    %ebx, %eax
        addl    $2, %ecx
        cltd
        idivl   %ecx
        testl   %edx, %edx
        jne     L8
        .p2align 4,,15
L3:
```

And it is clear it is doing both the multiplication and the division each iteration.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. Instead of this:

```
while((n%d!=0)&&d<r)
```

you can write

```
while((n%d!=0) && d*d < n)
```

Comment: Although note that computing `sqrt` once may actually be better than doing multiplication in a loop.

Comment: the multiplication can also be saved in a variable. also, it is possible that compiler will do it automatically.

Comment: No, because `d` is changed each iteration, its square also has to be calculated each iteration.

Comment: Anyway which one will surely be better?? calculating square root or using multiplication.

Comment: better you consider user315052's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of checking if `d < sqrt(n)`, you can check if `d*d < n` so:

```
while((n%d!=0)&&d<r)
```

should be

```
while((n%d!=0) && d*d < n)
```

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm uses square root to reduce number of iteration in cycle. Greatly reduce. I don't know what problem you have with square root, but you can calculate square root approximately with [these algorithms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots) or just change `d` to `d * d`, `r` to `n` in this line `while((n%d!=0)&&d<r)` or just change `r` to `n` (but with losing performance)

Comment: sure using square root reduces the number of iterations.Its just that i want that it should not be calculate explicity ,instead it should use this on the go.